# Arquivo no formato JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

E ai galera tudo beleza?

Estou com uma dúvida meia boba, porém não consegui encontrar uma resposta.
Estive analisando alguns sites e vi que, ao invés deles chamarem uma requisição `$.AJAX` no servidor para popular dados de um `dropdown` por exemplo, eles chamam um `link` no formato `JSON`.

Por exemplo:

```
meulocal.com.br/cidades.json
```

Como posso criar esse arquivo? É vantajoso utilizar desta maneira?

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Você pode dar um exemplo disso? Não entendi a parte "chamam um link" sem JS?

Comment: Acredito que "chamam um link", é porque o AJAX manda uma requisição (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE...) para o endereço (logo, "chamando um link").  Tal endereço possui a extensão de `.json`. Eu entendi dessa forma e acredito que seja isso mesmo. Mas respondendo... Provavelmente o `.json` é estático ou é alterado periodicamente por outro processo (em PHP ou não), assim criando e alterando tal arquivo. Isso funciona como um cache, assim um conteúdo estático é sempre servido, ao invés de ter de pegar os dados de um banco de dados. Afinal, não é todo dia que tem uma nova cidade para selecionar?! :P

Comment: Opá agradeço o auxilio, referente a duvida é feito uma chamada via ajax sim porém no endereço que é no formato .json ao inves de chamar um arquivo no formato .php por exemplo..

Answer (score 4):

Você cria um arquivo *.json da maneira como você cria um arquivo de texto qualquer. Em um *.json pode ser declarado qualquer tipo de valor que seja aceito, como `null`, expressão de objeto `{}`, expressão de `Array` `[]`, valores numéricos, `String`, `Boolean` e `null`, portanto, não pode ser vázio.

Diferenças:

- Em um objeto você só pode declarar nomes de propriedades com aspas entre eles.
- se você quiser escapar caracteres, declare um \ para ficar assim: \n (ou `\\`, computadamente) na frente do caractere.

No JavaScript, o objeto `JSON` inclui dois métodos:

```
* `parse`: Interpreta uma string como JSON.
* `stringify`: Transforma um objeto em string, no formato de JSON.
```

Exemplo de interpretar:

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"version": 0.5}');
alert("Version: " + data.version);

// Exemplo; expandindo o objeto retornado

with(JSON.parse('{"a": "bla\\nbla", "b": true, "c": "ey"}'))
    alert("a: " + a), // -> "bla\nbla"
    alert("b: " + b), // -> true
    alert("c: " + c); // -> "ey"

// Exemplo: inline

alert("a: " + JSON.parse('{"a": "inline"}').a) // -> "inline"
```

**Lembrando**: Alguns navegadores velhos podem não dar o suporte ao objeto `JSON`. Isso não é preocupante, mas se você quiser detectar, faça uma condição assim: `typeof window.JSON === "object"`, ou use algum ["polyfill"](http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/) existente.

---

Vantagioso? Se você quer um projeto fácil de trabalhar, o JSON facilita a legibilidade e a manipulação dos dados. A desvantagem comparada à vantagem de dados separados por vírgulas (`,`), o que diminui a quantia de caracteres, é insignificante. Eu diria que é vantagioso.

---

A dúvida no seu comentário não é relacionada à JSON. Você pode indexar qualquer string em um objeto e indexar outro objeto em seguida. Isso é normal em linguagens como Lua, JavaScript, etc:

```
var object = {index: {b: true}};
alert(object.index.a); // undefined
alert(object.index.b); // true
alert(object.b); // undefined
```

Comment: Compreendi, estou com uma duvida no seguinte caso, faço um arquivo .JSON, nele vou ter um valor :

{ MT : {[1: 'AF', 2: 'CA']}, RS : {[12: 'TT']} }

A duvida é como que faço pra acessar a informação direta por exemplo MT, carregar dados referente apenas este estado em uma lista de JSON que possui todos os dados?

Comment: @Crazy Fácil! É só indexar `"MT"` no seu objeto JSON. Ex: `JSON.parse('{ "MT" : {"1": "AF", "2": "CA"}, "RS" : {"12": "TT"} }').MT`... e você pode indexar qualquer propriedade nesse objeto, até se não existir. Execute no seu console e verá.